Missing Approved requests - Broken API Access
I am a developer, and we are currently developing an application. Recently, we added new API permissions in SPFx.
After accepting the permissions and refreshing the page, almost all permissions were missing.
When I open the application, I see an error when trying to get a token:

What I have tried:

I checked the names to ensure they are correct.

I deleted the webPart/application/page and re-uploaded the application.

I deleted the SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal, which was re-created after about 1 minute.

I added the API permissions directly in the SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal. After that, the permissions appeared in approved requests, but they still didn’t work.

I approved the request via M365:
m365 spo serviceprincipal permissionrequest list
m365 spo serviceprincipal permissionrequest approve --id 
->
After this command, the request also showed up in the approved requests but still didn’t work.


It's worth mentioning that I don't have the 'SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal Helper' in my app registration (it was likely deleted more than 30 days ago, and I can’t restore it).
Does anyone know what's going on? How to fix it?
Additional info:
Spfx:v1.18.2
Node:v18.17.1

any update on this issue?

I have a related, but no exactly the same question https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/314433/13225

No, this was not a production environment, so we deleted it and recreated the application. We don't have this issue with the new environment
