SharePoint Admin Center API Access request not showing up after adding solution to App Catalog
Based on a discussion with a colleague who reported an unexpected behavior (very similar to Missing Approved requests - Broken API Access), I tried to deploy a test package in our SPO with the following configuration:
"webApiPermissionRequests": [
  {
    "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
    "scope": "User.Read"
  }
]

I first added it to a site collection's app catalog. Added the app to the site, also added the simple webpart to a page. No entry in the API access admin center requests list.
After a few hours, I removed the webpart, solution and package from the site collection scope (emptied also the 2 stages of recycle bin).
I repeated the steps, but this time on the tenant's app catalog. Same effect - no request in the API access list.
Appreciate your feedback on the following 2 topics:

When are the API access requests supposed to appear in the
SharePoint Admin center?
Has anything changed recently? I'm thinking
about the question linked above which indicates issues in the same
area.


you can add it manualy. Go here:
Next, upload your application to the app catalog. The permissions should appear.
